# Noob C help - looping inside a switch/case?

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, switch-statement, case

new to programming and I've been crunching away on this assignment for weeks now.
I have a very basic understanding of C and while I'm nearly finished I think I might have made a mistake choosing a switch case for this menu system.

So the main menu gives 6 options, this option has to have a check to make sure Z1 is greater than Z2

```
case 5:

printf("\nEnter value Z1:\n");
scanf("%f", &Z1);
printf("\nEnter value Z2:\n");
scanf("%f", &Z2);

if (Z1 < Z2){
printf("\nZ2 must be less than Z1...\n");
}
```

I just want to return the program back to the beginning of the case unless Z1 is greater than Z2. After reading the other question it seems you can't loop the switch case back unless the values satisfy the if statement. I have no idea what to write as part of the if statement.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, I'm tearing my hair out thinking I'm going to have to rewrite most of it.

Apologies if this is something really straight forward, I've looked for a good hour trying to find something and maybe I have seen the answer but just didn't understand it.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: You can use [goto statments](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_goto_statement.htm). Also, I suggest you to change your mechanism and create "infinte" loop inside your main function. In this way you can break or continue in any case you define.

Comment: Additionally, if you can provide larger portion of code which includes all switch-case statements; people may suggest better solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a `do {...} while (condition);` loop would seem very adapted ; it's very close to the `while` loop, exept that the condition is checked only after the code into brackets has been executed ; which implies your code into brackets has to be run at least once.
Here, it would be :

```
do {
    //get z1 and z2
} while (Z1 < Z2);
```

Comment: You're very welcome, every C programmer has been stuck with simple problems as yours when starting .... you now can validate the answer to notify your question has been answered to, so other SO users can concentrate on new problems. Good luck in your learning !